# Create "for loop" to merge several pairs of csv files

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, filter, merge

To start, I am a biologist who tracks the movements and behaviors of seabirds. On these seabirds I attach two separate biologgers that collect data at the same time. One is a GPS that records coordinates every 2 minutes, the other is called a time depth recorder (TDR) that records depth every 1 second (when the bird dives past a certain depth, the diving event can be considered a foraging dive). Combining these data will help identify spatially where the birds are diving for food. Thus, each bird I track has a pair of GPS and TDR data that need to be combined based on their time stamp. What would make life easier however, would be to batch process these with a For loop or something else since I have tracked over 20 birds and combining these one by one is quite tedious. I have very little experience writing loops and need assistance. Does anyone have any suggestions or advice?

What I have currently been doing is combining these two data sets one by one, per bird, by matching the timestamp on the GPS data (date) with the timestamp on the TDR data (DateTime), which filters out the depth data that have no corresponding coordinates.

```
# Read in GPS and TDR files for each bird
rh01gps <- read.csv(file.choose(), sep=",", stringsAsFactors = F, strip.white = T, na.strings = c(""))

head(rh01gps)
          x        y              date      id
1 -123.0033 37.69831 6/3/2018 01:02:00 2018_01
2 -123.0033 37.69826 6/3/2018 01:04:00 2018_01
3 -123.0032 37.69821 6/3/2018 01:06:00 2018_01
4 -123.0033 37.69829 6/3/2018 01:08:00 2018_01
5 -123.0033 37.69830 6/3/2018 01:10:00 2018_01
6 -123.0033 37.69832 6/3/2018 01:12:00 2018_01

rh01tdr <- read.csv(file.choose(), sep=",", stringsAsFactors = F, strip.white = T, na.strings = c(""))

head(rh01tdr)
      Date Pressure   Temp        Time          DateTime
1 6/3/2018    -0.94 25.203 12:00:00 AM 6/3/2018 00:00:00
2 6/3/2018    -0.94 25.203 12:00:01 AM 6/3/2018 00:00:01
3 6/3/2018    -0.94 25.203 12:00:02 AM 6/3/2018 00:00:02
4 6/3/2018    -0.94 25.203 12:00:03 AM 6/3/2018 00:00:03
5 6/3/2018    -0.94 25.203 12:00:04 AM 6/3/2018 00:00:04
6 6/3/2018    -0.94 25.203 12:00:05 AM 6/3/2018 00:00:05

# Create a dataframe with dates from TDR file that match GPS datetime (many 
# more data points from TDRs than GPS, need to filter out dates that won't 
# have a match in the GPS file)
rh_gps_tdr <- subset(rh01tdr, DateTime %in% rh01gps$date)

# Merge newly created data
merge <- cbind(rh_gps_tdr, rh01gps$x, rh01gps$y)

# Rename longitude (rh01gps$x) and latitude (rh01gps$y) columns to "x" and "y"
colnames(merge)[colnames(merge)=="rh01gps$x"] <- "x"
colnames(merge)[colnames(merge)=="rh01gps$y"] <- "y"

# Subset data to filter out unnecessary columns
rh01_gt <- subset(merge, select = c(5, 6, 7, 2, 3))

# Combined GPS coordinates plus pressure data.
head(rh01_gt)
           DateTime         x        y Pressure   Temp
1 6/3/2018 01:02:00 -123.0033 37.69831    -0.94 24.828
2 6/3/2018 01:04:00 -123.0033 37.69826    -0.91 24.703
3 6/3/2018 01:06:00 -123.0032 37.69821    -0.94 24.625
4 6/3/2018 01:08:00 -123.0033 37.69829    -0.94 24.578
5 6/3/2018 01:10:00 -123.0033 37.69830    -0.91 24.531
6 6/3/2018 01:12:00 -123.0033 37.69832    -0.94 24.516

write.csv(rh01_gt, "RHAU01_2018_TDR&GPS.csv")
```

The code I have provided works for processing one birds' set of data, but I would like to see if there is a way to run this for every bird in one process.

Comment: One way to do it is to use `pmap()` from the `purrr` package. I would suggest to wrap your code in a function that takes as arguments: bird-id, dataframe1, dataframe2. You can then create three lists: bird-ids, all dataframes1, all dataframes2. Then call it with `pmap()`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I will give that package a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put your code in a for loop. This loop should work as long as there are equal number of csv files of each one and they have the same name pattern. In my test, the file names were rh01gps.csv, rh02gps.csv… and rh01tdr.csv, rh02tdr.csv… 
I had to set the date format because otherwise it didn´t work (note that I have assumed that your date format is dd/mm/yyyyy). I have changed the `subset` as well, because if there is a date column I think it is not necessary to use DateTime column (feel free to change it).

```
# your directory with all the csv files
setwd('yourpath')

# list tdr files by pattern 'tdr'
tdr.list<-list.files(pattern='tdr')

# list gps files by pattern 'gps'
gps.list<-list.files(pattern='gps')

# starting loop
for (i in 1:length(gps.list)) 
{
  # open each csv
  tdr<-read.csv(tdr.list[i], sep=",", stringsAsFactors = F, strip.white = T, na.strings = c(""))
  gps<-read.csv(gps.list[i], sep=",", stringsAsFactors = F, strip.white = T, na.strings = c(""))

  # set date format 
  gps$date<-as.Date(gps$date, '%d/%m/%Y')
  tdr$Date<-as.Date(tdr$Date, '%d/%m/%Y')

  # Create a dataframe with dates from TDR file that match GPS datetime (many 
  # more data points from TDRs than GPS, need to filter out dates that won't 
  # have a match in the GPS file)
  rh_gps_tdr <- subset(tdr, Date %in% gps$date) # subset made with date

  # Merge newly created data
  merge <- cbind(rh_gps_tdr, gps$x, gps$y)

  # Rename longitude (rh01gps$x) and latitude (rh01gps$y) columns to "x" and "y"
  colnames(merge)[colnames(merge)=="gps$x"] <- "x"
  colnames(merge)[colnames(merge)=="gps$y"] <- "y"

  # Subset data to filter out unnecessary columns
  gt <- subset(merge, select = c(5, 6, 7, 2, 3))

  # get the file number to have it in the output file
  filenumber<-substr(gps.list[i], 3,4) # 3 & 4 are the position of the number in the name (rhXXgps.csv)

  # writing csv file
  write.csv(gt, paste0("RHAU", filenumber, "_2018_TDR&GPS.csv"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Was much simpler than I realized to throw my original code into a loop. Greatly appreciated and educational for me.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Please accept my answer  [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)